# HAProxy + Netty: tcp-check makes Netty throw "connection reset by peer" exception

Tags: tcp, netty, thrift, haproxy

I am using Facebook's [Nifty](https://github.com/facebook/nifty) to run a TCP-based Thrift application. I want to load balance the requests so I am trying to setup HAProxy as the load balancer. The load balancing part works great. The `server check` part actually works great. If I take down one server, HAProxy sees it and directs traffic to the other.

What *does not work* is the `tcp-check` option. Every request it makes forces Netty to throw a `java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer` Exception.

So, HAProxy is closing the connection and Netty is still chatting. What is strange though is that the `tcp-check expect binary 5550 # UP` is working!

Here is my config for reference:

```
defaults
    mode tcp
    timeout connect 5000ms
    timeout client 50000ms

listen thrift
    bind *:9090
    mode tcp
    balance roundrobin
    option tcpka
    retries 3
    option tcp-check
    tcp-check send-binary 80010001000000135379734f7073536572766963653a636865636b0000000000
    # tcp-check expect string UP
    tcp-check expect binary 5550 # UP
    server thrift01 127.0.0.1:4444 check inter 10s
    server thrift02 127.0.0.1:5555 check inter 10s
    timeout connect 20s
    timeout server 30s
```

Again, connections work. Load balancing works. Regular SYN/ACK check works. But when I turn on the `tcp-check` I get errors on the server.

```
[2016-10-06 17:47:17,586] [nifty-server-worker-5]  ERROR c.f.nifty.core.NiftyExceptionLogger - Exception triggered on channel connected to /127.0.0.1:39010
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:64)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks.